# How to show that the sigma-algebra of the preimage of the Borel set, is the same as the sigma-algebra of the preimage of sets that can generate Borel?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. The smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ that ensures the measurability of $X$ is called the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$, and it's denoted by $\sigma(X)$:
$$\sigma(X)=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(B)\subset\Omega:B\in\mathcal{B}\})$$

How can I show that $\sigma(X)$ can also be written as $\sigma(\{X^{-1}(G)\subset\Omega:G\in\mathcal{G}\})$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is a subclass of sets that generates $\mathcal{B}$?